Striking the Earth! The True Magic of M&M?
Was wondering if this works not only RAW, as this feels...too funny to be RAI.
Inanimate objects are Defenseless, meaning that you can make Finishing Attacks against as a DC 10 to get a critical hit (pg. 250), typically for a +5 circumstantial bonus to the attack's resistance DC. However, this text is not the Improved Effect text of Critical Hits (pg. 240), nor does it have grammar able to replace that text, stating the Critical Hit comes with a +5 rather than forgoing the critical hit effect for a +5 or simply just not being a critical hit in the first place. Oddly enough Finishing Attacks resisted well enough by minions are not automatic recipients of the highest degree of the attack's effect, instead with text talking of how 3+ degrees of success with a Finishing Attack will kill the target.
This is concerning, because this means Defenseless targets have a +5 to the DC's of such attacks thrown at them, and get a additional Critical Effect applied to them like the following.

Alternate Effect: The critical hit results in an alternate effect for the attack, like a use of extra effort for a power stunt (see Extra Effort in The Basics chapter), except the character suffers no fatigue as a result. (pg. 240)

It took me a couple looks because more often than not having arrays is just...better than using this effect, given just hitting the target normally tends with a effect you already have with a +5 to the Effect Rank is usually strictly better. However, why attack your target? Strike the Earth and suddenly have access to a Variable Attack! Can't hit the target? Apply a Area Extra to the attack so it applies to characters in the surroundings, or make it a Ranged Attack linked to Ranged Create to make the debris from the earth fall from the sky through falling created object rules, or Transform the Earth into air to make a character fall, or make it a Summon Power (since all it needs is the same range) and make a buddy that can move and attack at range for you! You can even make a Healing AoE as a result of certain descriptors, healing both the structure you attack and allies in the area through some kind of ki, magic, or spiritual effect depending on whatever descriptors you have available. Contagious Affects Objects Healing may be a better way of doing it, since you can Power Attack while applying to multiple targets through spreading it through the ground (potentially even back to yourself depending on how you rule Contagious). Fun stuff, however...
Why not use this ruling? It's dumb. Players pretty much start playing a entire new game, but even then most players probably have Alternate Effects of everything they already want, which they can use despite them not being limited to Attacks and not being limited to Finishing Attacks or natural Critical Hit. It's only really useful in games where your GM has banned Variable but simultaneously are okay with you pulling a fast one and pulling this ruling out of your pocket to bypass said rule.
So yeah, is this ruling RAW and what is the text in the official books that deems it so? I figure there might be something in the more recent books but I have yet to read them as I only GM with the PHB, and the Knockback & Disaster Rules from the Gamemaster's Guide.

I think that you've encountered one of the situations where the text might not have been updated with new mechanics defined elsewhere. The text for Finishing Attack is pretty unambiguous that the effect of doing the Finishing Attack is to get a Critical Hit on the target, adding +5 to the resistance check DC. I think it would take some fairly tortuous logic to claim that you should get two rolls on the table, so to speak. It seems to me that the Finishing Attack text may date from before the effects of Critical Attack were expanded (particularly since it is very similar to the 2E "Coup de Grace" attack against helpless targets), or is constraining the use of the "Critical Attack" here to increasing the DC.
As regards using an Alternate Effect instead of increasing the DC, if you allow it, I could see it as valid, although note that the GM is the ultimate arbiter of things like Power Stunts, so they can decide if it makes sense for the descriptors and the game (to use a slightly silly example, a player stating that they're using their ability to punch things really hard to turn the wall they're hitting into curative medicine for their teammate, aka power-stunting a Healing effect, generally wouldn't fly, unless the GM and the player agree that this legitimately makes sense in the game world, say that walls are regularly made of medicine in this world, or everyone has reality warper powers such that you just have to believe that it would work). For a Finishing Attack, something like stunting an Affliction seems like it makes a reasonable descriptor ("Since Dr. Min is unable to resist, I'd like to use Finishing Attack, and do a pressure point attack to freeze him in place instead of my usual damage." "OK, that would be an Affliction, should be at the same ranks as your effect. Roll for the attack.") while something like gaining the power of Flight would be right out. Unless, of course, that's simply the sort of campaign everyone agrees to be in.
As we have discussed before, Rule 0 being what it is, the GM is free to interpret the text however they feel will make the game most interesting and fun for their players, so if you, as the GM, would prefer to have a Finishing Attack have both the +5 and the effects of a Critical Hit, that is explicitly something you are allowed to do. I don't agree with that interpretation, but I'm not in your game.

The logic is sound despite the result being dumb. The Finishing Attack Effect isn't the Critical Hit Increased Effect, as they have different effects beyond the +5. "With" by definition means the effect explained thereafter is accompanying the critical hit effect, not replacing the original. There are plenty of dumb things within the game that are RAW and RAI, it being "tortuous logic" doesn't change what the text means, nor does intention really change what the game actually says.

My goal is to play the game as literally written as possible, as the game should work as the game has been put to written text, beyond what the designers necessarily meant as many designs go beyond the designer's initially intend through emergent gameplay. Rather than asking if a "interpretation" is alright, I ask for what the rules written literally mean, and how someone playing Rules as Literally Written ought to use the rules if they're looking to play the game in front of them, not a interpretation that can be dismissed as "rule 0 lets you do anything you want". Hope that clears things up.

@FriendlyNeighborhoodChicken: I believe that just applying the +5 is the true intepretation, based on how prior editions worked, and how I've seen the game played, including games with Steve Kenson, they guy who made the system. But, as I said, it is your game, and you can play it as you wish.

Again I'm not asking for a interpretation, but rather what the system is literally written as. While I am sure this is not how anyone plays the game currently, I'm asking if what I've stated is how the game written in the book works if you use its text and the dictionary as gospel, and if the gameplay I've described emerges from that text when read by that method, because even the people that have made some of the coolest mechanics out there whether rocket jumping or combos in fighting game where made unintentionally and not well known as concepts until later on in the game's lifespan.

{nods} And, as far as I'm concerned, the literal reading of the book is that you get the +5 effect like with a Critical Hit, and that three degrees or more of failure with an intent to kill means you do so. It's there and in the section about attacking objects.

Does a Finishing Attack automatically kill minions with PL 20 minion with 40 Toughness no resistance check required?

That is a good question, which would depend on whether the intent of the line was that "you get a Critical Hit, giving you +5 to the save DC" which would suggest the text of Critical Hit applies and the Critical Hit means they don't get to save, or if the +5 is meant to apply as if you made a Critical Hit (which would neatly explain it not having text for AE, additional effect, etc).
Frankly, since minions are meant to be disposable (even if potentially not a walk in the park), I'd say yes.

Do all Increased Effects have the Finishing Attack effect applied?

@FriendlyNeighborhoodChicken: No. Extra Effort to increase the rank of an effect makes no mention of it being a Finishing Attack. If you're asking if, e.g. a Snare Affliction with the intent to kill done as a Finishing Attack will kill the target if they fail their resistance roll badly enough, I would say that that would be the case, although it would be partially dependent on that effect having a valid means to kill (Healing, for example, has no damaging effect), noting of course that a Power Stunt could be used to change the effect to one that could kill.

Increased Effect is the terminology for the +5 effect listed in Critical Hits. I'm asking if that effect also has the effects written in Finishing Attack, not if Extra Effort can be used to conduct Finishing Attacks (that would be weird).

@FriendlyNeighborhoodChicken Ah. No, there's no indication that they mean for a critical hit to work the same as a finishing attack.
